# gdb command in Eclipse expression view

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm debugging some code with Eclipse CDT and GDB, and some strings are in UTF-8, so I use `x/sh <buffer name>` in the debugger console to display them.

Is there a way to put GDB command as expressions in the Expression view? I have a buffer called `Work1`, so I tried to add `x/sh Work1` as an expression, but that didn't work.

When adding an expression, Eclipse uses the `-var-create` command to create a variable object. After reading the documentation I don't think it's possible to provide a custom format with `var-set-format` that fits what I need.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to directly use a GDB expression with Eclipse in a more automated way than the Debugging Console?
2. Is there a way to specify a more flexible display format with `var-set-format`?
3. Is any other way I can achieve this, like using the Memory View?

Thank you!